# Formatting an email to start a new line

Tags: vba, outlook, ms-word, formatting

I produced Word VBA code to send an email with an attachment.

It works, apart from the `vbNewLine` command.

When the email arrives in the inbox the complete message is on one line.

```vb
Sub SendEmail_Example1()

Dim EmailApp As Outlook.Application
Dim FilePath As String
Dim FileName As String
Set EmailApp = New Outlook.Application

Dim EmailItem As Outlook.MailItem
Set EmailItem = EmailApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

EmailItem.To = "name@xxx.com"
EmailItem.Subject = "Test Email From Word VBA"
EmailItem.HTMLBody = "Hi," & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "This is my first email from Word" & _
vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
"Regards," & vbNewLine & _
"Chris"
FilePath = "https://d.docs.live.net/00f559247767a0d7/Documents/NT/Template/"
'Set Correct Filename
FileName = FilePath & "Test Booking Form.docx"

EmailItem.Attachments.Add FileName

EmailItem.Send

End Sub
```

I would like the email to look like:

> Hi
>
> This is my first email from Word
>
> Regards
> Chris

I tried carriage returns as well as linefeeds and also using the hex equivalents.

Comment: With `HTMLBody`, you need to use `HTML` - So you do not use `vbNewLine` - Instead you use `<br>` - So like this: `"Hi,<br><br>This"`

Answer (score 0):

The [HTMLBody](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.htmlbody) property returns or sets a string representing the HTML body of the specified item, so it must be a valid HTML document where the `vbNewLine` value doesn't make any sense. You need to use the `<p>` [HTML tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_p.asp#:%7E:text=The%20tag%20defines%20a,Use%20CSS%20to%20style%20paragraphs.) or just `<br>` in the markup. The `<p>` tag defines a paragraph. Browsers automatically add a single blank line before and after each `<p>` element.

Otherwise, you may try using the [Body](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.body) property:

```
EmailItem.Body = "Hi," & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "This is my first email from Word" & _
vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
"Regards," & vbNewLine & _
"Chris"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `<br>` tag (which does not need to be closed):

```
EmailItem.HTMLBody = "Hi," & "<br><br>" & "This is my first email from Word" & _
vbNewLine & "<br>" & _
"Regards," & "<br>" & _
"Chris"
```